Fluid Simulation only shows particles, but no mesh. Mesh option was enabled. Can I bake the mesh around it somehow?

I am trying around with Blender Fluid Simulations and have successfully simulated this specific level numerous times. However, now that I increased some of the settings, it seems that the domain is not converted into a mesh anymore and I am only able to see the particles, which simulated as expected.
Although I had a mesh before I did these setting changes, it is now not visible and I am wondering  :

If I can somehow bake a mesh around my particles
What setting I changed that led to this issue

Thank you for your time. I appreciate any help.
File: 

maybe switch to Solid mode? Or please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Just to avoid confusion and making your question appear as if it were off-topic: there is a paid third-party addon called FLIP Fluids where we would advise to ask the developers and close the question, but you are using Mantaflow so your title could be a bit misleading (yes I know the simulation type is FLIP, but still...).

@GordonBrinkmann I have no connection to the third party addon, I am using vanilla blender. I'll edit the title then.

@moonboots If I switch to solid mode, I can only see the domain as a cube encompassing my scene.

@shacolate Yes, I see it is vanilla Blender. I just mean it appears like that, people scrolling through the question titles might skip yours when they think they can't help because they don't have FLIP Fluids, it might just help get more people to look into your problem.

please share your file

we have no idea what your experience level of Blender is - but everytime you change just one settings of your simulation - you have to bake it again. If that doesn't help, pls provide blend file as moonboots asked already 2x for it. thx.

I tested around a bit and found out that the mesh stops generating when the Resolution Division is set around 512. Rendering the same simulation with 256 works. I will attach the file soon, though the particles are not there anymore after reopening the file.

File added to the question.
